# Is there way to expose all the components, directives, pipes and models from angular library with single export in public-api.ts?

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have created an Angular 11 module to library and it has 100+ components, pipes and directives. I want to export all the items with a single line of code, but while importing I don't see those. Is it possible to do so ?

```
    public-api.ts
----------------------------------
    export * from './lib/shared.module'
```

Here, shared.module.ts contains all the component, directives and pipes.